# Как подтянуть куки в Environment - Postman

Tags: javascript, json, test-automation, testng

Для того что бы положить значение из ответа в `jSon` в `Environment` - я использую форму:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("имя в энваироменте", jsonData.значение);
```

А вот как забирать значение из `cookie`, полученное в ответе, и записывать их в `Environment` - Для использования в следующем запросе ?